# jquery mobile delay slider event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I try to start the slider event when the last value was selected. The idea is, to create something like combination lock.
I've this solution:

```
<div data-role="page">
<label for="slider1">first</label>
<input data-type="range" name="slider1" id="slider1" value="10" min="0" max="20" />
<br>
<label for="slider2">second</label>
<input type="range" name="slider2" id="slider2" value="10" min="0"  max="20" />
<br>
<label for="slider3">third</label>
<input type="range" name="slider3" id="slider3" value="10" min="0" max="20" />
</div>

 var seconds = 3,
 timer;
 $("#slider1, #slider2, #slider3").on("slidestop", function(e) {
 var slider1_value = $('#slider1').val();
 var slider2_value = $('#slider2').val();
 var slider3_value = $('#slider3').val();
 var update = function() {
 if (slider1_value == 15 && slider2_value == 2 && slider3_value == 2) {
  alert("Great!!!");

 } else {
  alert("Try it again!!!");
  }
 }
 if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
 timer = setTimeout(update, seconds * 1000);

 });
```

Maybe there is a better solution, because the user have to wait for 3 seconds before something happens?

[Here is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kubus1234/3tyuh4aa/2/#&togetherjs=bKzpE9sDIn)

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```
$("#slider1, #slider2, #slider3").on("slidestop", function(e) {
  var slider1_value = $('#slider1').val();
  var slider2_value = $('#slider2').val();
  var slider3_value = $('#slider3').val();
  if (slider1_value == 15 && slider2_value == 2 && slider3_value == 2) {
    alert("Great!!!");
  }
});
```

**EDIT**

I have made you a fiddle as well: https://jsfiddle.net/EliteSystemer/7hpbanq9/

My reason for the change is that I would not want to have an error casted each time my combination is wrong, but only when it's correct.

The code above provides automatic verifiation each time one of the sliders are changed. A different approach is to add a button for manual verification. Please let me know if that's what you want, and I'll provide an example for that as well.